# Как собрать html вот так?

Tags: node.js, webpack

Пытаюсь найти видео или же статью с наглядным примером, как собрать так страницу, что не будет показан тебе твой код как в web.telegram. Можете пожалуйста скинуть видео или же статью example?)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Это называется минимизация кода. Раз вы указали тег `webpack`, то держите инструмент под `webpack` - https://webpack.js.org/plugins/compression-webpack-plugin/

Comment: а можете пожалуйста скинуть пример? Я нечего адекватного не нашёл

Comment: По ссылке одна из самых адекватных в мире документаций в принципе. Полный пример довольно не быстро воспроизводить. Давайте вы уточните для меня свои знания и тогда я дополню ответ, добавлю примеры. Я так понимаю, что с `webpack` вы не работали?